# Can you query webform settings?

Tags: webforms

I have the task to query data from my phpMyAdmin database and also to query the emails from each webform 'to_email' field. Is there a way to query that data using MySql? I was able to do it using php, but I can't seem to find a way to access the webform email settings by using only MySql.

Edit: I just found out that all the website data is stocated in the database. For example, you can find the data in your 'to_email' field inside your node.type. row, in a blob.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. you can try the following query to find all entries in 'cache_config' that contain 'to_email':

```
SELECT cid, data
FROM cache_config
WHERE data LIKE '%to_mail%'
```

This will get you all the blobs that contain the given field.
Even more than that, you can look for what follows 'to_mail' to get the actual mail by using the LOCATE and SUBSTRING functions.